# Transforming a graph into another

Tags: graphs

Let's say I have 2 graphs $g_1$ and $g_2$, each determined by a set of nodes and a set of non-oriented edges.

I also have 2 operations that can be done on a graph: *edge contraction* and *node split*:

[image: Operations]

Nodes have a position so it is possible to do the operation as specified on the figure, and we can assume that the neighborhood of a node is roughly planar.

**How can I have a list of operations transforming $g_1$ into $g_2$ ?**

I know there is a [graph edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_edit_distance) that find the cost of such a list of operations, but what is interesting me is the list itself. **Are there some articles that I can read that answer (even partially) this question ?** I wouldn't want to do a brute force approach, since even with 2 operations the number of possibilities is enormous.

Please note that there are some constraints verified these graphs:

- each node has at least 2 edges connected to it
- there can be only one edge between 2 given nodes (so no redundant edges)

Comment: What explicitly occurs during $V'_s$ split to $V_s$ and $V_t$? Why isn't $V_s$ included in any edges that contain the top two vertices of the graph? Is this a planar transformation only?

Comment: Vertices have position, and we can consider the neighborhood of $V'_s$ to be roughly planar, so it is possible to find which side of $V_lV'_sV_r$ an edge lie to know if it should attach to $V_t$ or $V_s$.

Comment: Can you edit the question to incorporate this crucial information?  We want questions to be self-contained, so people don't have to read the comments to understand your question.